# Passing values between view and controller query in grails

Tags: javascript, grails, parameter-passing

I have a grails controller(Tablev1classController.groovy) with a sql query which looks like:

```
class Tablev1classController {

def dataSource

def listjson = {
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def rows = sql.rows("select date_hour, total_revenue as sales, visits, marketing,
                     organic, single_page_visits , total_units from tablev1 
                     where si_flag ='Serialized' ")
sql.close()
render rows as JSON
 }
 }
```

In views,I have a dropdown like the following:

```
<select id="si_flag" class="wrapper-dropdown">
<option value ="serialized">serialized</option>
<option value ="non-serialized">non-serialized</option>
</select>
var si_flag = document.getElementById('si_flag');
```

How can this value stored in variable 'si_flag' be passed as a parameter to the query defined in the controller(in the where condition).

Comment: Use jQuery ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You must have been tortured to end up with a name like that for your controller (which means that your model is called Tablev1class).

Comment: Didn't have an option there.The person working on the project before me gave that name for no reason and there is lot more to care about than the name of the controller,so, i didn't bother to change it.Will definitely think about it now though.Feel free to answer my question.Name won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Nisha

First thing you have to make sure that the varible `si_flag` is posted to the controller , since i can't see a post or ajax call in your code.

Then , re-write your query as follows :

```
def rows = sql.rows("""select date_hour, total_revenue as sales, visits, 
                       marketing,organic, single_page_visits , total_units 
                       from tablev1 
                       where"""+params?.si_flag""+""" ='Serialized' """)
```

Then everything works !!
To make sure your si_flag is having some value when posted to the controller. 
you can use

> `log.info(""Content of si_flag posted"+parmas.si_flag) or 
>   pritnln "Content of si_flag posted :$params.si_flag"`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the form values in controller by using params like below

```
class Tablev1classController {

def dataSource
def selected=params.si_flag

def listjson = {
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def rows = sql.rows("select date_hour, total_revenue as sales, visits, marketing,                   organic, single_page_visits , total_units from tablev1 where si_flag = '${selected}' ")
sql.close()
render rows as JSON
}
}
```